# Do otaku tend to be bullied?

Tags: culture

[Otaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku#In_Japan) in Japan are somehow equivalent to being geek, meaning they are tend to be bullied or looked down upon. That's why some don't admit that they are otaku because of shame. And there are certain cases of otaku becoming a [hikikomori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori), (an example of this is in [Welcome to the NHK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_the_N.H.K.) where the male protagonist is a hikikomori) wherein they isolate themselves or withdraw themselves from society and a [NEET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEET#Japan) (*Not in Education, Employment or Training*), where they remain jobless. How true are these cases and is it true that most of hikikomori and NEET are otakus (like Misaki Nakahara in Welcome to the NHK)? Or hikikomori and NEET people tend to become otaku (just like Tatsuhiro Sato in Welcome to the NHK)?

Comment: Although your question was close as off topic, you can change the scope of your to be more inline with [the FAQ](http://anime.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). A question such as "Is the portrayal of otaku/NEETs (abuse) in anime/and manga like in X (e.g. Welcome to the NHK) series reflect real life situations?"

Comment: @Krazer What difference does that make? You are basically saying that "Does X happen in real life?" should be changed to, "X happened in anime Y, does that happen in real life too?" I fail to understand why one is off-topic and the other is not.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai By ensuring the topic stays upon the context of anime and manga, the answers are more likely to stay on topic and be more answerable. We don't want this conversation trailing off into something about Otaku, NEETs, unemployment, and societal pressure in Japanese society.

Comment: @Krazer That's all this question is no matter which way you word it. I agree that it's off topic either way.